# can't display google map marker

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

here is the php code

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $doc->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);

  $newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
}

$xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();
echo $xmlfile;

?>
```

here is html with javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
    };

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = eval('customIcons'+'.'+type) || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon.icon),
    shadow: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon.shadow)
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

i am just following https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 and i don't know what is wrong with my code i checked the database, the xml. its all working..
any help would be very much appreciated. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have illegal whitespace in this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api    /js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Change it to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_phpsqlajax_map_v3_notWrkgA.html) (using a local copy of [this](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_expectedoutput.xml) for the data)

Comment: my original code here is the same as you posted but it still doesn't show the markers. can you see something else that might be wrong?

Comment: Then post a link to your live map that shows the problem or look at the working example I posted. Is your code the same as that?

Comment: i changed the downloadurl to what is the expectedoutput xmlfile and it worked! so does it mean that my php code that i posted is not outputting the database as xml? if so how can i fix it.thanks.

Comment: Your question says "i checked the database, the xml. its all working.. ", is that not true?  If you provide a live link to your page, we might be able to help more.

Comment: i am doing it in a localhost. i am still practicing it. and the codes i used are what i posted. yes i said that. thats why im confused. im sorry

Comment: Are you running a webserver on your local host?  What browser are you using?  What javascript errors does it report?  Is the XML generated from your database the same as the "expected output"?

Comment: yes. i am running it on google chrome and firefox.  Timestamp: 11/12/2012 2:45:13 AM
Error: TypeError: xml is null
Source File: http://localhost/andresite/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html
Line: 32 my database is the same..copied all the database.

Comment: Sounds like your XML is being served with the wrong headers. `header("Content-type: text/xml");` Are you running a webserver?

Comment: @Andremalupet i also used this cod in my site and it's work properly, check your database data is exist or not. if exist then tell me i'll send to u my own code

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 var icon = customIcons['simple'] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
```